# Determining Time Complexity for Recursive Functions

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Hi so I'm trying to get the time complexity in Big O notation for these functions below however I am not quite sure how to go about doing so. I have gotten the first 2 but the last 3 I don't know how to go about solving for it.

For R1 I solved it by doing it out. The function is run 3 times for the numbers less than it and then 3 times for the numbers below it and so forth. Then it comes out to 3^n. Therefore its O(3^n)

For R2 it would be O(log n) because for each iteration it goes by half. I did so by using 1024 for n. 1024 -> 5+(512) -> 5 + 5 + (256) and so forth getting 5*log2n which is O(log n)

For R3 I believe it is O(log log n) because of some reasoning that I kind of made up and dont really understand and its really just guessing. Because it is multiple sqrts I decided it was log log n. However I don't know how to properly go about solving this or the rest of the functions (R4, R5). I'm fairly new to algorithms. Help and explanations would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

```
def R1(n):
    if (n == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return R1(n-1) * R1(n-1) * R1(n-1)

def R2(n):
    if (n == 0):
        return 1
    if (R2(n//2) >= 5):
        return R2(n//2) + 5
    else:
        return 5

def R3(n):
    if (n <= 1):
        return 1
    sum=0
    for ii in range(int(math.sqrt(n))):
        sum += R3(int(math.sqrt(n)))
    return sum

def R4(n):
    if (n <= 1):
        return 1
    count = 1
    tmp = R4(n//2)
    for jj in range(n):
        ii=1;
        while (ii<n):
            if (tmp < math.exp(ii+jj)):
                count += 1
            ii*=2
    return R4(n//2) * (count % 2)

def R5(n):
    if (n == 0): return 1
    if (n == 1): return 3
    return R5(n-1) + R5(n-2)*R5(n-2)
```

Comment: What is the difference between a square root and log? are they the same?

Comment: im actually not sure. I just googled what sqrt would be time complexity wise and people said log log n

Comment: @joesmite I think you are going to need some basic math help/tutoring to get this topic down. The square root of a number is the same as raising the number to the 1/2 power: n^0.5. Which is very different than log log n.